# Laptop shuts down after 1-1.5 minutes from start up

Tags: windows-7, windows

Toshiba L640

http://www.cnet.com/products/toshiba-satellite-l640-14-core-i3-350m-windows-7-home-premium-64-bit-3-gb-ram-250-gb-hdd-series/specs/

I recently had an issue with cooling so I disassembled it and dusted it all and reassembled it. This however did not fix the issue so I took it apart again and replaced the fan and the stock thermal paste. I cleaned the CPU and gpu with isopropyl and applied a thin layer of paste (and cleaned a small spill). Replacing the fan did improve the airflow drastically but now it won't stay on for more than 1.5 minutes regardless of weather I leave it in BIOS, launch safe mode or normally. Although launching normally did cause a blue screen. Launching safe mode does get to the log in screen but I don't have time to log in before it shuts off.

I realise there are probably a dozen things I could have done that permanently damaged my laptop during disassembly and it's a bit of a stretch to expect a working solution.

Cheers for any advice you have.

Comment: are you sure the fan is plugged in and rotating?

Comment: "Replacing the fan did improve the airflow drastically but now it ..."

Comment: Are you sure the cooling unit is properly mounted? It sounds like there’s an air gap or the like.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is not much you can do. Howevery, try the usual.

1. Reset BIOS
2. Take out everything (HDD, CD-ROM, RAM, Battery)
3. Connect the PowerPlug and start the Notebook

If your Notebook keeps working now, then one of those things is to blame.
If it still shuts down then your only choice is to take it apart again and clean it again.

However, my guess is that you did not apply the Heatpipe correctly (or not enough Paste) and your CPU keeps overheating.

Comment: Figured as much, cheers I'll try that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

if your fan is spinning normally, your bios configuration is using default-safe-compatible settings and you have not installed any incompatible or broken drivers, your hardware is damaged.